# Why is the exponential integral $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ the antiderivative of $\frac{e^x}{x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am aware that $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ is indeed the antiderivative of $\dfrac{e^x}{x}$. However, the exponential integral is defined as: $$\operatorname{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}t\,dt$$
The integrand has $e^{-t}$ instead of $e^t$, and the limits of integration are not, for example, from $0$ to $x$. So, how exactly does it follow that it's the antiderivative of $\dfrac{e^x}{x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Covering what happens for any $x\ne0$.

---

The [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definitions) is actually defined in terms of the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), meaning that for $x>0$, we define

$$\operatorname{Ei}(x)=-\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_{-x}^{-\epsilon}\frac{e^{-t}}t~\mathrm dt+\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}t~\mathrm dt\right)$$

For $x>0$ we may also split the integral up as follows:

$$\operatorname{Ei}(x)=\operatorname{Ei}(1)-\int_{-x}^{-1}\frac{e^{-t}}t~\mathrm dt$$

And likewise for $x<0$:

$$\operatorname{Ei}(x)=\operatorname{Ei}(-1)-\int_{-x}^1\frac{e^{-t}}t~\mathrm dt$$

which are both easily differentiated using the fundamental theorem of calculus, now that we have finite bounds, and the chain rule to get

$$\operatorname{Ei}'(x)=\frac{e^x}x$$

---

Note that where you choose to split the integral is arbitrary. As long as you choose to split the integral on the same side of zero as $x$ the above will work.

Answer (score 4):

You have 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Ei}(x)=\int_{\infty}^{-x}\frac{e^{-t}}t\,dt.
\end{align}
Then, using the Chain Rule,
$$
\operatorname{Ei}'(x)=\left.\frac{e^{-t}}t\right|_{t=-x}\,\times (-1)=\frac{e^x}x.
$$
Since you are concerned with $\infty$, fix some $K>0$ (to avoid problems at the origin) and then 
$$
\operatorname{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^K\frac{e^{-t}}t\,dt-\int_{K}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}t\,dt.
$$
The second integral is a constant, so it disappears when you differentiate.

Comment: But the lower limit of integration is $\infty$ as opposed to a number. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: No, it isn't. I have addressed that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ei}{Ei}$Substitute $x=-t$ so that
$$\Ei(x)=-\int_{-x}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt=-\int_{-t}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{-t}(-dt)=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{e^x}{x}dx.$$
Do you see it now?

Comment: How can you take the derivative when the lower limit of integration is $-\infty$. I don't think you can differentiate $\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ in general.

Comment: @bjorn93 No you can't, but you can in this case. To elaborate, the antiderivative of $e^x/x$ tends to a finite value (in particular, $0$) as $x$ goes to $-\infty$, so essentially we can treat the value at $-\infty$ as a constant. So we are justified in differentiating here.