# Questionable statement in Abramowitz and Stegun: Exponential Integral Function

Tags: calculus, special-functions

I have in front of me the ninth (1972) printing of Abramowitz and Stegun's *Handbook of Mathematical Functions* (1964).

In Section 3 of the introduction, "Auxiliary Functions and Arguments" they discuss the Exponential Integral Function, which is presented in the following form:

> The exponential integral of positive argument is given by

$$\operatorname{Ei} (x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac {e^u} u du$$

This looks suspect to me: the domain encompasses an obvious pole at $u = 0$ which does not at first glance look removable.

The way I have been accustomed to seeing this defined (as found in the Schaum *Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables* (1968) Chapter $35$ is:

$$\operatorname{Ei} (x) = \int_x^{+\infty} \frac {e^{-u} } u d u$$

which makes more sense.

I am wondering whether the statement "The exponential integral of positive argument" is incorrect, and that perhaps it should say for *negative* argument?

The power series expansion of the first of these is given in Abramowitz and Stegun as:

$$\operatorname{Ei} (x) = \gamma + \ln x + \frac x {1 \times 1!} + \frac {x^2} {2 \times 2!} + \frac {x^3} {3 \times 3!} + \dots$$

while from the Schaum Handbook definition you can derive:

$$\operatorname{Ei} (x) = -\gamma + -\ln x + \frac x {1 \times 1!} - \frac {x^2} {2 \times 2!} + \frac {x^3} {3 \times 3!} - \dots$$

Can anyone shed any light on this? I would work out the derivation from the A&S definition except for the fact that I really don't know how to handle the singularity.

Comment: Maybe it needs a Cauchy principal value? See [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralEi/07/01/01/0002/)

Comment: @TymaGaidash  How do I find out whether it does or does not need a Cauchy principal value?

Comment: Maybe the answer to [MSE 3398257](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398257/) will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abramowitz and Stegun on page 228 states (with \pvint instead of \int)

> $$ 5.1.2 \qquad \mathrm{Ei}(x)=-\,\int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm{d}t=%
> \int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{e^{t}}{t}\mathrm{d}t \qquad (x>0) $$

where the integrals are [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)
integrals because of the obvious pole. What was missing on page X was the
slight difference in the regular integral sign and the Cauchy principal
value integral sign. The [DLMF $6.2.5$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E5) states exactly the same thing as A&S $5.1.2$.

Tthe correct series valid for all real $\,x< 0\,$ **or** $\,x>0\,$ (cf.
[DLMF $6.6.1$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.6.E1) with $x$ instead of $|x|$) is

$$ \mathrm{Ei} (x)=\gamma +\ln |x| +\sum_{n=1}^\infty 
\frac{x^n}{n\, n!}  $$

where for some reason the DLMF version is qualified by $\,x>0.$
Note that the power series converges for all real $\,x\,$ and
the derivative of the expression is $\,\frac{e^x}x\,$ for all
$\,x\ne 0\,$ and thus the only difficulty is justifying the
choice of the constant $\,\gamma.$

---

Note that while $\,\mathrm{Ei}(x)\,$ is defined only for real
$\,x\ne 0,\,$ there is a closely related function as given in
[DLMF $6.2.1$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E1) as

> The *principal value* of the exponential integral $\,E_1(z)\,$
> is defined by
> $$ 6.2.1 \qquad \qquad \qquad E_1(z) = \int_{z}^\infty 
> \frac{e^{-t}}t \mathrm{d}t,\qquad\qquad z\ne 0, $$
> where the path does not cross the negative real axis or pass
> through the origin. As in the case of the logarithm
> ($\S4.2$(i)) there is a cut along the interval
> $\,(-\infty,0]\,$ and the principal value is two-valued on
> $\,(-\infty,0).$

Comment: I'm well out of my depth, then. Looks like I have a long way to go yet. I have some studying to do.